# PHP 7 session_regenerate_id Failure and PDO Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, magento, session, mysqli, pdo

I have upgraded from PHP 5.6 to 7 and use a custom session handler script to manage sessions in my database so I can have better control over my users. Everything works fine as before except one thing.

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

After a user successfully logs in, to avoid session fixation, we call session_regenerate_id. Worked fine with PHP 5.6, not so with PHP 7:

> [14-May-2016 02:04:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/xxxx/protected/class.database.php:38
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/xxxx/protected/class.session.php(37): Database->query('SELECT data FRO...')
>   #1 [internal function]: Session->_read('kuq04akaagkjd5n...')
>   #2 /home/xxxx/protected/user_auth_fns.php(705): session_regenerate_id(true)
>   #3 /home/xxxx/public_html/passengersdir/login.php(42): login_user('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', NULL)
>   #4 {main}
>     thrown in /home/xxxx/protected/class.database.php on line 38
>   [14-May-2016 02:04:07 UTC] Recoverable error: session_regenerate_id(): Failed to create(read) session ID: user (path: ) in /home/xxxx/protected/user_auth_fns.php on line 705

Apparently session_regenerate returns false but PHP 5.6 let it slide. This is the official response from PHP:

- PHP 7.0 and up does not allow buggy return values from user save handler.
  user read handler MUST return "string" data for success always.
- Native save handler must return SUCCESS for successful cases including non-existing session data.
- `FALSE`/failure means "Something wrong in read" such as permission/network/etc errors.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71187

Some people found a workaround here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2827

> It appears to be an issue with the read function not always returning a string. As a temporary fix I cast the return value for the read() function in the SessionHandler as a string.

I don't like workarounds. I can simply remove `session_generate_id` and it works like the good old times, but you open to session fixation.

Ideally I would like to solve this issue OR find a better way to fight session fixation after successful login. Thank you for looking.

Here is the code in question:

```
public function __construct(){ // this is class.database.php
    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function query($query){ 
    // this throws Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/opentaxi/protected/class.database.php:38
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}
public function execute(){
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}    

// this is from class.session.php
public function _read($id){ 
//this is /home/opentaxi/protected/class.session.php(37): Database->query('SELECT data FRO...')
$this->db->query('SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');
$this->db->bind(':id', $id);
if($this->db->execute()){
  $row = $this->db->single();
  return (string)$row['data']; // I have the workaround that's not working!
}else{
  return '';
}
}
```

Comment: ***"Here is the code in question:"*** I don't see `session_generate_id` on it.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom handler MUST return a string ALWAYS in PHP7. I ran into the same problem testing on my Dev. What I would do (since there's no failure cases here) is the following

```
if(gettype($row['data']) != 'string') return ''; // It's not a string so return empty for failure
return $row['data'];
```

Now, as to your error, your problem seems to be a bad reference. Without seeing the code that calls it, this looks like your problem

```
try{
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
}
// Catch any errors
catch(PDOException $e){
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

So the catch block is catching any failures and setting an internal variable. Something is not checking that to make sure you have a PDO object. You might want to echo `$e->getMessage();` and see if you're getting any exceptions. Because the error you posted is indicating that the above block failed.

Comment: I showed full code above in the edit. I tried if(gettype($row['data']) != 'string') return ''; that's not fixing it. The weird thing is that I'm not getting into the catch block...?

Comment: Well, you need to echo out PDO errors then. Something is failing therebecause, according to the error, `$this->dbh` is `null`